# Hiding and unhiding row on different tab using a checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use a checkbox that when unchecked hides some rows on another tab and when checked has the rows unhidden.  I can get it to work on the current active tab but not on the other tab. Here is what I have:

```
If CheckBox1 = False Then
    Sheets("Compliance Certificate").Select
    [21:25].EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Sheets("Compliance Certificate").Select
    [21:25].EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code could be simplified as a line.

- Assumes CheckBox is on `Sheet1`, modify as needed

```
Sheets("Compliance Certificate").Rows("21:25").Hidden = Not Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1
```